# WPF datagrid drag and drop target indicator

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, drag-and-drop

I have a WPF datagrid where a user can drag and drop various rows to reorder them.  However, I need an indicator that will display where the row will be inserted.

I've tried various 'hacky' ways of doing it, including detecting mouse move events and inserting a blank indicator row where the mouse is.  Unfortunately, it seems that while dragging rows, none of my mouse move events are getting fired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [UIElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.dragenter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) class provides several events that you can use.
Those are:

- DragEnter
- DragOver
- DragLeave
- Drop

The first two are the one you can use.

```
<DataGrid DragOver="MyGrid_DragOver"
          DragEnter="MyGrid_DragEnter"
```

I had to use both to get my drag and drop working.

I start the Drag operation by reacting to a move mouve event:

```
private void MyGrid_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {    
        var dragSource = ...;
        var data = ...;
        DragDrop.DoDragDrop(dragSource, data, DragDropEffects.Move);
    }
}
```

Then you code the event handlers on the target control (your DataGrid):

```
private void MyGrid_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    this.DragOver_DragEnter(sender, e);
}

private void MyGrid_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    this.DragOver_DragEnter(sender, e);
}
```

Then you can set the `Effects` propery to give a visual feedback to the user:

```
private void DragOver_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    // code here to decide whether drag target is ok

    e.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;
    e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Move;
    e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    e.Handled = true;
    return;
}
```

Check out this response on MSDN too: [Giving drag and drop feedback using DragEventArgs.Effect](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/bb1eb2a9-e280-431b-a8f4-6dd98bae6d21/giving-drag-and-drop-feedback-using-drageventargseffect?forum=wpf)